# Using ee.FeatureCollection.iterate makes object too large for exporting

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm having issues with using iterate on a featurecollection.

I have reason to believe that one of my methods downstream is duplicating elements, so I want to assign sequential integers to my rows to keep track of them and to ensure that there are no duplicates being added.

However, the only changes that I'm making is this integer row. When I do this and try to export this FeatureCollection, the API returns the error that the object is too large.

I'm using the iterate function to assign the sequential IDs. To test, I mapped a function that added a random number to the ID column, and the asset had no problem being exported. So I think something is wrong with the iterate function below:

```
nhd = nhd.sort('AreSqKm', false);
var first = ee.List([ee.Feature(null, {"N": -1, "Remove": true})]);

//Add these IDs to each image. 
var addID = function(feat, list){
  var num = ee.Number(ee.Feature(ee.List(list).get(-1)).get("N"));
  feat = ee.Feature(feat).set({"N": num.add(1)});
  return(ee.List(list).add(ee.List(feat)));
};

//Iterate through and add ID, Merge to images. 
var tl = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List(nhd.iterate(addID, first)));
nhd = tl.filterMetadata("Remove", "not_equals", true);

Export.table.toAsset({
  collection: nhd, 
  description: "NHD_addID", 
  assetId: "NHD_addID"
});
```

Any time I try this, I get the error "Error: Encoded object too large", and a google search does not help too much in finding a detailed explanation. Am I messing something up with the .iterate function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `addID` iteration function, in order to produce its output, is building up an `ee.List` of *every feature in the collection.* This will always fail if the collection is too large to fit in memory at once.

Unfortunately, I don't know of a way to attach an iteratively computed property to a collection in the way you want. The closest feature that exists is `.randomColumn()` but as the name suggests, that adds random numbers, not sequential ones.

---

However, there might be another method: every feature in a collection has a unique `.id()` string (also known as the property `system:index`). It's not guaranteed to be sequential — the format you get depends on the table you started with and also the processing steps — but each of those steps that might merge/join/flatten/etc. two collections (and therefore be able to duplicate features) will systematically produce guaranteed unique IDs for each one, **by adding text rather than by renumbering.**

For example, suppose that your original table had feature IDs like `0000000000000000325b` (actual example from WDPA). Then if you did some kind of computation that matched a feature two different ways and put both of them in the result, you'd find that they have IDs like `1_0000000000000000325b` and `2_0000000000000000325b` or similar. Thus, you can look for the pattern of your original IDs and see if there are any duplicates of *those*.